# Generating HTML links in a Zeppelin Impala output table column?

Tags: impala, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to figure out a way to generate HTML links in an output table from an Impala query in a Zeppelin note (one link for each row, and they would be in their own column in the table). Clicking the link would cause a relevant data file to be downloaded from the file system to the user's computer (that's the easy bit).

The tricky bit is how to generate the link in an Impala output table. Is there a particular SELECT query that would do this? Can I generate a custom template for the output table that Zeppelin uses to display Impala results? Is there some other solution?

Each link would have a slightly different href as there would be a different file on the system related to each output row, I think generating the href would be straightforward based on the row data but this is more about what syntax would cause an HTML link to be generated and displayed in a column?

Thanks

Comment: Could you use Zeppelin's %angular interpreter to display an html table instead of using the Zeppelin native table display? It doesn't seem like the native table can have custom html currently.

Comment: @Golammott  Thanks. That's a good idea actually but I need to run a query using Impala (or Hive) on a very large dataset. Not sure how to do an SQL query in the Angular interpreter and make it use Impala or Hive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work while using Impala with the existing Zeppelin `%jdbc` Interpreter as that interpreter strictly reads/interprets SQL statements and offers no ability to manipulate your result data using code.

The following two workarounds might help

**Option 1**: Instead of using `%jdbc` Interpreter to run the Impala query use `%python` or `%spark` (Scala) interpreters to run the Impala query via JDBC. Then do your data manipulation (cast to html link) in the same cell.

Example using Python Interpreter with jaydebeapi:

```
%python
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect("com.cloudera.impala.jdbc3.Driver", "jdbc:hive2://myhost.example.com:21050/;auth=noSasl")
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select link, data from impala.table")
row = curs.fetchone()

result = """%table
linkItem\tdataItem
"""

while(row):
    result += "%html <a href='{}'>google</a>\t{}\n".format(row[0], row[1])
    row = curs.fetchone()
    
print(result)
```

**Option 2:** More of a hack, continue to use the JDBC interpreter to run the Impala query, but then retrieve the results of the JDBC paragraph using the Zeppelin API with requests. Then parse the results and add the `%html <a href>` to the parsed data.

```
%python
z.z.run("20210309-195201_1615214407")
paragraph_endpoint = "http://{}:8890/api/notebook/{}/paragraph/{}".format("10.241.XX.XX", "2FYFABCD1", "20250210-223517_1845423213")
paragraph_r = requests.get(paragraph_endpoint)
paragraph_resp = json.loads(paragraph_r.text)
rows = paragraph_resp["body"]["results"]["msg"][0]["data"].split()

result = """%table\n""".format(rows[0])
for row in rows[1:]:
    result+="%html <a href='{}'>google</a>{}\n".format(row)
print(result)
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, very helpful. Is there an endpoint/API to run a paragraph and get the results in one call, i.e. avoid having to do a run (which will display the table in the UI using the standard display system) and then call the paragraph endpoint to get the table data?

Comment: Unfortunately not that I have seen. Run a paragraph sync API looks close, but I still dont think it gives you the full result in the response.